# Regex to match part of sentence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a part of sentence that comes after a negation word (e.g. don't, can't, not) until the next punctuation and attach "_NOT" at the end of every word of that part of sentence, for example:
"I really like turkey, but not chicken with tomatoes, because I'm allergic" becomes
"I really like turkey, but not chicken_NOT with_NOT tomatoes_NOT, because I'm allergic".

Initially my approach was to run regex that looks something like this:

```
(dont|cant|not)(.*)[!?,.]
```

to get the part of the sentence that I'm interested in, then go word by word and attach _NOT and then run *str.replace(oldPartOfSentence, newPartOfSentence)*.

This almost works, but the search is not greedy, if I have a punctuation at a later point, it will find a longer part-of-sentence than it needed. Additionally it does not support the case if I have a negation word, but there comes no punctuation mark after it (then it should add negation to every word from the negation word to end of string).

For example running that regex on the example sentence gives

```
[('not', ' chicken with tomatoes')]
```

but if I have full stop at the end, I get:

```
[('not', " chicken with tomatoes, because I'm allergic")]
```

How do I fix this, and is there a more efficient solution for this as a whole? For example is there a way to update the regex to automatically attach the "_NOT" at the end of the sentence through *re.sub()*?

Comment: Change `.*` to `.*?`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the first part of the problem. Is it possible to make some regex that also attaches the "_NOT" for each word in the matched string?

Comment: @Limonup: I don't think so, not directly. I initially thought to try using a positive look behind assertion that checked for the not-like word and matched at each word that followed it without intervening punctuation, but at least for Python, look behind assertions must be fixed width, and trying forward search hits issues with searches not handling overlapping matches while needing to omit matching the not-like word itself makes that (AFAICT) impractical as well. You'd need to chain the regex calls.

Comment: I'm not aware of an auto-updating regex.. You're better off matching what you need and then applying whatever you want. Edit : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Steven's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172341/regex-to-match-part-of-sentence#comment54152293_33172341), just change the `.*` to `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

You can't do the substitution with a single regex AFAICT (see the reasons in [my comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172341/regex-to-match-part-of-sentence#comment54152957_33172341)), but a chained set of substitutions will work:

```
def add_nots(m):
    notty, following = m.groups()
    return notty + re.sub(r'(\S+)', r'\1_NOT', following)

notted = re.sub(r'(dont|cant|not)(.*?)(?=[!?,.]|$)', add_nots, original_string)
```

Note: I made an extra change to the regex to use positive look ahead assertions to avoid capturing the terminating punctuation (or end of line, which is a change; the original version you gave with just the non-greedy fix wouldn't match when the notted line component ended at the end of the string, not with one of the recognized punctuation marks), so the punctuation/end of line doesn't need to be captured and reproduced by the `sub` replacing function.

Also, if you're going to do this a lot, interspersed with other regexes, you probably want to pre-compile your regex objects instead of relying on the `re` cache:

```
# One-time, up front, compile
word_finder = re.compile(r'(\S+)')
not_finder = re.compile(r'(dont|cant|not)(.*?)(?=[!?,.]|$)')

def add_nots(m):
    notty, following = m.groups()
    return notty + word_finder.sub(r'\1_NOT', following)

notted = not_finder.sub(add_nots, original_string)
```

Comment: Note: `add_nots` _could_ be an inline `lambda` that explicitly calls `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` instead of unpacking `m.groups()` then using the named values (and in fact, while testing this out, that's how I did it). But in the interest of not writing unreadable one-liners (particularly since this is SO, and _you_ need to see the components that are involved), I stuck with an independently defined named function that breaks up the flow into logical components and uses self-documenting names.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.